# The Framework Tiles from SP-Starter-Kit is not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I pulled the tiles out of the starter kit here, https://github.com/eoverfield/sp-starter-kit. I get NO errors when I do 'npm install' and run 'gulp serve'. Everything works fine locally, but when I package the sppkg, I come up with the error below:

ERROR message when I put it in SPO
[image]

NPM and Node Version
[image]

I think it has to do with the versioning of my NPM and Node? Or maybe the 'launch.json' needs to have the directory rather than the localhost:4321? I am lost and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need run `gulp serve` to test the solution(so the webpart could load the webpart js library from your local).

Or deploy your the solution to CDN or SharePoint library so the webarpt could load the webpart js from CDN or SharePoint library.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-deploy-spfx-webparts-to-sharepoint-library/